Django modification of UserCreationForm
My problem is that I am trying to modify the Django default UserCreationForm and its default messages, but it does not work. I also heard that some of the checks and initial messages are defined separately and should be customized separately, but I did not find a lot on that. I tried to search around, but most of what I found was either old and not working for current django version or did just modify the fields and not the error messages.
I am importing the UserCreationForm in forms.py like this:
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

And then I tried to modify it like this: The fields and everything is completely functional just the messages are still the default and not the custom I was trying to set.
class UserSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label="custom",
                               error_messages={'required': 'custom.',
                                               'unique': 'custom.'})
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="custom", widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                error_messages={'required': 'custom.'})
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Potvrďte custom", widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                error_messages={'required': 'custom.',
                                                'password_mismatch': 'custom.'})

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields
        error_messages = {
            'password_mismatch': {"password_mismatch": "custom"},
            'password_too_short': {"password_too_short": "custom"},
            'password_common': {"password_common": "custom"},
            'password_entirely_numeric': {"password_entirely_numeric": "custom"},
        }

If someone knows how to solve this, please let me know. I would appreciate any feedback.

Does this answer your question?

For you to be able to overwrite the error message with either the Meta or the form field error_messages attribute, the ValidationError must be passed through ModelForm._update_errors. This does not happen for the errors raised by the password validation - they're added directly, without the extra step:
class BaseUserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def _post_clean(self):
        super()._post_clean()
        # Validate the password after self.instance is updated with form data
        # by super().
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password:
            try:
                password_validation.validate_password(password, self.instance)
            except ValidationError as error:
                self.add_error("password2", error)

Overwrite _post_clean
One option would be to overwrite the _post_clean method to call _update_errors instead of add_error:
class UserSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    ...

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta): 
        ...
        error_messages = {
            NON_FIELD_ERRORS: {
                'password_mismatch': "custom mismatch",
                'password_too_short': "custom too short",
                'password_common': "custom common",
                'password_entirely_numeric': "custom numeric",
                "password_too_similar": "custom similar",
            }
        }

    def _post_clean(self):
        # Skip BaseUserCreationForm._post_clean:
        super(forms.ModelForm, self)._post_clean()
        # Validate the password after self.instance is updated with form data
        # by super().
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password:
            try:
                password_validation.validate_password(password, self.instance)
            except ValidationError as error:
                # Re-instantiate the ValidationError with an error_dict.
                # Without this, the messages that _update_errors iterates
                # over are strings (as returned by ValidationError.__iter__) 
                # instead of ValidationError instances. But we need 
                # ValidationError instances to know which error code to look for.
                _error = ValidationError({NON_FIELD_ERRORS: error.error_list})
                self._update_errors(_error)

Replace error messages
Alternatively, you could inspect form._errors after validation has finished and replace the error messages by hand:
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label="Potvrďte custom",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        error_messages={
            "required": "custom.",
            "password_too_similar": "foo",
            "password_too_short": "bar",
        },
    )

    def _post_clean(self):
        super()._post_clean()
        for field, error_list in self._errors.items():
            if (
                field == NON_FIELD_ERRORS
                and self._meta.error_messages
                and NON_FIELD_ERRORS in self._meta.error_messages
            ):
                error_messages = self._meta.error_messages[NON_FIELD_ERRORS]
            elif field in self.fields:
                error_messages = self.fields[field].error_messages
            else:
                continue
            for error in error_list.as_data():
                if error.code in error_messages:
                    error.message = error_messages[error.code]

Note that the password validation errors are added to the field "password2" - so you need to declare your custom error messages using the field's error_message attribute.

The second option does not skip BaseUserCreationForm._post_clean, so it's probably the cleaner solution in the long run.
